# Should I use static or inline?

Tags: c++, c, static, inline

I am writing a header-only library, and I can’t make up my mind between declaring the functions I provide to the user `static` or `inline`. Is there any reason why I should prefer one to the other in that case?

Comment: Both will serve the purpose. The difference will come when a `static` variable is declared inside the function. `inline` function will create only 1 copy of that variable for all files, however `static` function will create 1 copy per file.

Comment: are you writing code that should work well as **both C and C++**? the rules of the languages differ.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf C++, but I am interested by both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They both provide different functionalities.

There are two implications of using the `inline` keyword(§ 7.1.3/4):

1. It *hints* the compiler that substitution of function body at the point of call is preferable over the usual function call mechanism.
2. Even if the inline substitution is omitted, the other rules(especially w.r.t *One Definition Rule*) for inline are followed.

The `static` keyword on the function forces the `inline` function to have an internal linkage(*inline functions have external linkage*) Each instance of such a function is treated as a separate function(*address of each function is different*) and each instance of these functions have their own copies of static local variables & string literals(*an inline function has only one copy of these*)

Comment: Does it stand true on C++11?

Comment: +1 @qdii: It might be important to emphasize that not only will each `static` function have it's own static variables, literals and such, but also the code will be replicated (if it is not inlined) and that will both bloat your binary and affect performance (less likely to fit in the instruction cache)

Answer (score 4):

Note: this answer is for C++. For C, see [caf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466170/464581). The two languages differ.

`static` has two relevant meanings:

- For a function at namespace scope, `static` gives the function *internal linkage*, which in practical terms means that the name is not visible to the linker. `static` can also be used this way for data, but for data this usage was deprecated in C++03 (§D.2 in C++03 Annex D, normative). Still, constants have internal linkage by default (it's not a good idea to make that explicit, since the usage for data is deprecated).
- For a function in a class, `static` removes the implicit `this` argument, so that the function *can* be called without an object of the class.

In a header one would usually **not use internal linkage for functions**, because one doesn't want a function to be duplicated in every compilation unit where the header is included.

A common convention is to instead use a nested namespace called **`detail`**, when one needs classes or functions that are not part of the public module interface, and wants to reduce the pollution the ordinary namespace (i.e., reduce the potential for name conflict). This convention is used by the Boost library. In the same way as with include guard symbols this convention signifies a lack of module support in current C++, where one is essentially reduced to simulating some crucial language features via conventions.

The word `inline` also has two relevant meanings:

- For a function at namespace scope it tells the compiler that the *definition* of the function is intentionally provided in every compilation unit where it’s used. In practical terms this makes the linker ignore multiple definitions of the function, and makes it possible to define non-template functions in header files. There is no corresponding language feature for data, although templates can be used to simulate the `inline` effect for data.
- It also, unfortunately, gives the compiler a strong *hint* that calls to the function should preferably be expanded “inline” in the machine code.

The first meaning is the only guaranteed meaning of `inline`.

In general, apply `inline` to every function definition in a header file. There is one exception, namely a function defined directly in a class definition. Such a function is automatically declared `inline` (i.e., you avoid linker protests without explicitly adding the word `inline`, so that one practical usage in this context is to apply `inline` to a function declaration within a class, to tell a reader that a definition of that function follows later in the header file).

So, while it appears that you are a bit confused about the meanings of `static` and `inline` – they're not interchangable! – you’re essentially right that `static` and `inline` are somehow connected. Moving a (free) function out of a class to namespace scope, you would change `static` → `inline`, and moving a function from namespace scope into a class, you would change `inline` → `static`. Although it isn’t a common thing to do, I have found it to be not uncommon while refactoring header-only code.

Summing up:

- Use `inline` for every namespace scope function defined in a header. In particular, do use `inline` for a specialization of a function template, since function templates can only be fully specialized, and the full specialization is an ordinary function. Failure to apply `inline` to a function template specialization in a header file, will in general cause linking errors.
- Use some special nested namespace e.g. called `detail` to avoid pollution with internal implementation detail names.
- Use `static` for static class members.
- Don't use `static` to make explicit that a constant has internal linkage, because this use of `static` is deprecated in C++03 (even though apparently the deprecation was removed in C++11).
- Keep in mind that while `inline` can’t be applied to data, it is possible to achieve just about the same (in-practice) effect by using templates. But where you do need some big chunk of shared constant data, implemented in a header, I recommend producing a reference to the data via an `inline` function. It’s much easier to code up, and much easier to understand for a reader of the code. :-)

Comment: As an update to the final point in your answer, as of C++17 you CAN use `inline` on a variable to ensure that it has only one instance across translation units.

Answer (score 2):

`static` and `inline` are orthogonal. In otherwords, you can have either or both or none. Each has its own separate uses which determine whether or not to use them.

Comment: I think `none` option is not possible for header only library. Also, the OP is asking when to use. This answer is incomplete. Unfortunately my +1 is now locked; you can consider it for the profile-pic and not for the answer. :|

Comment: @iammilind The question asks about choosing between the two. My answer is attempting to explain that you don't have to choose between them. You can use them both or neither one. Also, the OP doesn't specify that he is only talking about header files.

Comment: the effects are orthogonal, that's true. still for the in-practice usage there is a connection, so that one not completely uncommon editing operation is to change `static` → `inline` for a set of functions, or vice versa. namely when moving function between namespace scope and class scope.

Answer (score 1):

If that function is not sharing the class state: `static`. To make a function `static` can benefit from being called at anywhere.

If the function is relatively small and clear: `inline`

Comment: +1 For addressing member functions. Note that `static` has a different meaning for non-member functions.

Comment: `If the function is relatively small and clear: inline`, that's not an issue with modern compilers which decide the macro style inlining in their own way.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is based on the C99 rules; your question is tagged with both C and C++, and the rules in C++ may well be different)

If you declare the function as just `inline`, then the definition of your function is an *inline definition*.  The compiler is not required to use the inline definition for all calls to the function in the translation unit - it is allowed to assume that there is an external definition of the same function provided in another translation unit, and use that for some or all calls.  In the case of a header-only library, there will *not* be such an external definition, so programs using it may fail at link time with a missing definition.

On the other hand, you may declare the function as both `inline` *and* `static`.  In this case, the compiler must use the definition you have provided for all calls to the function in the translation unit, whether it actually inlines them or not.  This is appropriate for a header-only library (although the compiler is likely to behave exactly the same for a function declared `inline static` as for one declared `static` only, in both cases inlining where it feels it would be beneficial, so in practice there is probably little to be gained over `static` only).

Comment: The rules in C++ are indeed different. In C++ an `inline` function has external linkage by default, and there is no restriction on using internal linkage things from the function. In C++ the preferred usage for header-only code is just `inline`, with implied external linkage.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: In C too, `inline` functions have external *linkage* by default, but they do not necessarily provide an external *definition*.  It sounds as though if the OP wants their header-only library to be useable in both C and C++ then they should be using conditional compliation to use `static` only in C.